# Pilot communication with ATC partially unreadable

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications

Can anybody decipher this pilot's landing request due to moderate turbulence (some unreadable words...).   Thanks !
https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/03kDM9-xQ7Oyz3kUaeRJj6M5Q#AUDIO-2021-12-03-07-51-16

Answer (score 4):

This is what I hear.

**“Boblika tower, Air China Niner Two Niner request”**

**“Air China Niner Two Niner request to uh climb to eleven thousand six hundred meters due to uhh moderate turbulence”**

It is the same person making both transmissions as you don’t hear the tower respond to the first request.

The tower name is most probably incorrect, but if you went through a list of control towers you might be able to pick it out and correct the spelling.

It may not even be a tower that the request is made to. It seems unlikely a tower facility would be controlling flights operating at 11,600 meters, but in Russia or China, anything may be possible.

Comment: Sweet. Pretty much a copy of my answer 

Comment: Thank you very much for helping on this one !   I was understanding a request to land so I was confused with the altitude mentioned,

Comment: Thank you very much to both of You, Mike and Jpe, for helping on this one !   I was understanding a request to land so I was confused with the altitude mentioned.   Now, I "clearly" understood that it was a request to climb.  Thanks again !  I'm not myself a native english speaker but was pretty baffled by the pilot's accent !      As for the facility called by the crew, I looked at the planned route of    Air China 929 ( Shangai PVG to Tokyo NRT)  and the associated facilities: I found that KCZ Kōchi airport might be the one called, but the first word of the  pilot comm is totally unreadable.

Comment: Anyway, Thank you very much again, as I now understand this communication !    Cheers !

Answer (score -1):

If anybody's interested, here is what OpenAI's Whisper transcription model produces, verbatim:

> Air China 939 request to climb to 11,600 meters due to moderate turbulence.

Looks like it filters out the filler noises and pretty accurate.

Here is the Python script:

```
import sys
import openai

openai.api_key = # YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY

filename = sys.argv[1]

audio_file = open(filename, "rb")

result = openai.Audio.transcribe(
  model="whisper-1",
  file=audio_file,
  max_tokens=1024,
  speaker_labels=True,
  prompt="Transcribe this airplane communication audio file, differentiate between speakers where possible. Return markdown format."
)

# Save to Markdown file
out_file = filename.replace('.mp3', '.md')
with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(result['text'])

print(f"Transcription saved to {out_file}")
```

Note: I'm not sure the prompt does anything, I tried to get a nice markdown format out of it, but it just produces the plain text. Maybe too short, but would need to try with more files.

Comment: I like this answet